# Set Combobox value from id of the set using Data Bound Items in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, combobox

I have a Combobox `cbAnimal` that is bound to a table like this from a Data Source that displays only the names of the animals.

```
+-----------+-------+
| id_animal |  name |
+-----------+-------+
|      3    | Cat   |
|      4    | Dog   |
|      6    | Cow   |
|      8    | Horse |
+-----------+-------+
```

The `cbAnimal` displays the list of the names perfectly and I can retrieve the `id_animal` by selecting its name using the ValueMember property.

The problem is that later on I also need to **set** the value of the `cbAnimal` by the `id_animal`

e.g. I'll pass the id 6 and on the Combobox it will have to display "Cow" and still allow to be modified.

I tried using:

`cbAnimal.SelectedIndex= myAnimal.id_animal;`

But it dind't work.

Is it possible to do this with a property of the Combobox?

EDIT: I should clarify what I'm trying to do:
When the winforms is loaded I need to make it display the default value as "Cow" instead of Cat (which is the first element), if the Id_animal that is passed is 6 of course.

Comment: Make use of the `SelectedValue` property instead of SelectedIndex

Comment: `SelectedIndex` will be return/take an Index value (0-3) for each item in the list. `SelectedValue` will return/take a value corresponding to the `id_animal` for the selected item

Comment: @JayV It still shows the first element of the dropdown ("Cat") instead of "Cow" when I open the form again.

Comment: If you close an reopen the Form, you reset the DataSource, so it goes to the first item. If you're passing a value to the Form, to set the ComboBox selection, do that in Form.Load or Form.Shown, not the Form constructor.

Comment: @Jimi Should I leave the field "Selected Value" in "None" or should I select one of the two columns? I'm referring to the options in the [Design] tab when you expand the Combobox

Comment: You set the `SelectedValue` to match a value in the Field defined  by the `ValueMember`, causing the selection to move the Current record. What you set in a designer is useful in the designer, to evaluate the results of the selection change. Note that I've never used the Data Designer and I never will: too much boilerplate code is generated that is not needed at all. -- If you want to set a default value in the ComboBox, set the `SelectedValue` in the Form.Load event handler.

Comment: Thanks @Jimi! I set it in the Load event and it worked perfectly with the `SelectedValue` property.

Answer (score 1):

Doing it without the list

```cs
public class animal
{
    public int id {get; set;}
    public int name {get; set;}
    public override string ToString() // <-- new addition
    {
        return name;
    }
}

// Fill combo
comboBox.Items.Add(new animal() { id = 1, name = "dog" });
comboBox.Items.Add(new animal() { id = 2, name = "cat" });
comboBox.Items.Add(new animal() { id = 3, name = "rat" });

// later you can do this to select item by ID
comboBox.SelectedIndex = 
    comboBox.Items.Cast<animal>().ToList().FindIndex(a => a.id == 2);
```

or just loop

```cs
for(int i = 0; i < comboBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (((animal)comboBox1.Items[i]).id == 2)
    {
        comboBox.SelectedIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @JuaniElias this answer shows how to do it without list

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```cs
public class animal
{
    public int id {get; set;}
    public int name {get; set;}
}

// Fill
var animalList = new List<animal>(); 
// and bind
comboBox.ValueMember = "id";
comboBox.DisplayMemeber = "name";
comboBox.DataSource = animalList;

// later you can do this to select item
comboBox.SelectedIndex = animalList.FindIndex(a => a.id == 2);
```

and even if you don't keep reference to `animalList`, you can do this

```
comboBox.SelectedIndex = ((List<animal>)comboBox.DataSource).FindIndex(a => a.id == 2);
```

Comment: This is great but is there other way without using a list. I still don't know how this properties work.